# display a different URL than the php page user is actaully on

Tags: php, .htaccess, lighttpd

I am building a search engine for my website in PHP and right now when one submits the search form, either by hitting enter or clicking the submit button, it takes them to a url that looks like this: `myDomain.com/search.php?search=searchedTerm&submit=`

Is there a way that I can ' change ' the url so that it looks something like myDomain.com?search=searchTerm
Just so that the location of the file that powers the search engine is not revealed?

My test server can accept .htaccess files, but my deployment server is running LighttPD.

So if there needs to be server configurations that need to be done to achieve this, I ask that they be done in .htaccess or a solution that can work with a server running LighttPD

Or if someone has a solution for both cases, that would be great!

So, in summary, I am wondering if it is possible to submit the search and go to the results page without displaying the location of the php document that preforms the search.

If this is possible in PHP, .htaccess, or lightPD settings please let me know.

P.S. Where I got this idea from is that Google doesn't reveal the location of the files performing the searching.

Comment: plus a few million other dupes.

Comment: @MarcB Sorry, I ddin't mean for this to be a duplicate. I'll check the other post out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you'd be better off just updating your main index.php file to accept the search GET parameter and then including search.php if it exists:

```
  if( isset( $_GET['search'] ) ) {
    require( 'search.php' );
    exit( 0 );
  }
```

Comment: Correct. Using your index.php as a router will allow you to mask the file location, and route the contents based on the arguments supplied.